# Passing part of a multidimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I was wondering if it is possible to pass part of a multidimensional array in c++. For example say I have an array of three dimensions (size X * Y * Z):

```
int array[X][Y][Z];
```

And say I also have a function that takes a two dimensional arrays (size Y * Z) as one of it's parameters:

```
void function(int stuff[Y][Z]);
```

Is it possible to call the function like this?

```
function(array[x_var]);
```

As in like pass the x_var slice of the three dimensional array only and therefore passing a two dimensional array[y][z] in effect..

Or would I have to use a new two dimensional array, copy the slice into that, then pass that into the function?

Comment: Consider using a decent linear algebra library: look at BLAS in www.boost.org. Then you can just pass an object.

Comment: Why not simply try it and see what happens?

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers, so in both cases you are passing a pointer, not sure what you are trying to save/do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can! Only changing the dimensions order requires a rearranging, e.g. if you have 2-dimensional arrays, and a function which should take either a row *or* a column.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at the [Boost Multidimensional Array Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) as this makes it much easier to deal with slicing (which are called 'Views' in that library).  If you make your own multidimensional arrays with the C style syntax `int array[X][Y][Z]` then you can only pass a slice in one dimension.  For example, if you wanted to pass a row rather than a column then you can't easily do this with the C style syntax.

If you use a library like `boost::multi_array` then you will probably find that most of your code will work without modification (since you can also address elements as `array[x][y][z]`), the main change will be to defining the array to be the right size when you construct it.  Incidentally, you can also resize it more easily than in the C-style case (where the dimensions have to be fixed at compile time)